# Speed Improving Index

Tags: performance, indexing, sql-server-2012, excel-2013

I have a fairly basic query such as below that I am needing to execute very often and as fast as possible:

```
Select
     B.ID, B.FirstName, B.LastName
From 
    TableA as A
Join 
    TableB as B on A.ID = B.ID
Where 
    A.OtherID = @Input
```

So my thought was to create a stored procedure with parameters of `@Input`. I figure that since the execution plan was saved on the server side this would increase the speed.

I however want to increase it further and thought that maybe an Index might help. But I have not dealt with indexes much just read a little.

What all information would you need to help me build an index that can help? 
Would an Index help?

Also this stored procedure is going to be called from Excel 2013 if that makes a difference on something else we can do to speed it up.

We are using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: A stored procedure per se is ***NOT*** any faster than a properly parametrized ad-hoc query - in both cases, an execution plan is created upon first usage, and kept in cache and reused on subsequent calls.

Comment: Interesting I must have misread or misunderstood what I had read about that. But it would cut down on bandwidth by having the code on server side right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio is remarkably good at recommending indexes. Run your query and see what it says.

Without knowing more about your schema or the OLAP patterns, I can only make a suggestion...

Is "ID" the key field in TableA and/or TableB? If so, they're already indexed.

I'd say you're looking at two indexes:

1. An index on TableA for OtherID that includes ID. This will help SQL find values of OtherID and return the ID's associated with them.
2. An index on TableB on ID that includes FirstName and LastName. This will help SQL with the join and save a trip back to the rows for FirstName and LastName.

Comment: yes in tableA OtherID is the Primary Key and in TableB ID is the Primary Key. So it should already be setup the way I need?

Comment: That's part of the fun! I don't know if you're setup the way you need - play with indexes as I describe and see if your query improves.